# SharePoint List Item Lookup with Multiple List Source without using workflow

Tags: custom-list

I would like to ask if there are other way of populating list item data using a lookup reference to another list without using workflow. 
Sample scenario is.

- I added new item to my current list then lookup the column1 to sample
  List1 and return the value.
- If the item is not found in Sample List1, it will lookup to Sample
  List2.

Answer (score 0):

Without workflow your options comes down to

1. Use event receiver and handle item added event.
2. Use JavaScript + SPServices
3. Use JSOM
4. Use CSR

Comment: Thank you Amal for your reply. With that said, I think it's more complicated than having a workflow.

Comment: It's not complicated as it sounds. There are plenty of articles floating around to guide.

Comment: Another to add to the list would probably be a PowerShell script (you know I'm a fan), that would run once a day and compare the two lists.

Comment: That may be a good a idea to have a PowerShell Script. do you have some tutorial links for that? Thank you. :)